# Apache guacamole multi user connection cache issue

Tags: python, google-chrome, guacamole

Im using apache guacamole with tomcat 8

I have an issue which if im loggedin in a browser (chrome) tab, and i open another tab it is reconnecting me to the same user i have logged in the first tab, 
I do not want this behavior as i need it to be able to work with a lot of users on the same browser with different tabs.

I cant always open incognito \ clean cache.  ( and also 2 pages of incognito of the same webpage also redirect)

My python code which redirect to apache guacamle RDP connection is a simple redirect to html page:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, redirect
return render_template('gqm.html')
```

Somone has some recommandtion of a browser \ configuration i can change in tomcat or my python code?
To maybe send forced clear cookie\cache to this specific site connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by not giving a uniq user to a uniq connection, but giving the same user (guacadmin) and blocked the user from seeing home page, using nginx :

```
location / {
proxy_pass http://guacamole:8080/guacamole/;
rewrite ^.*api/session/data/postgresql.*/activeConnections.* /no_such_page last;
```

so when i redirect client to a connection using the url token he cannot do logout\home page as it will give him an error.